# My tensorflow keras model always gives 1.0 for every prediction. It's not working correctly

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am working on a website using Django project. I am taking sell prices (based on keywords) and making future price predictions and machine learning on the data recieved from ebay api database calls (keywords). I am using keras from tensorflow to make price predictions based off of a train_test_split from sklearn.model_selection. All my features and target (sell prices) array are scaled down between -1 and 1, with mean 0 and std. dev. of 1. All the predictions are coming back as 1.0 and I can't figure out why. It looks like I'm "overfitting" the model. I was wondering if someone could help me out. I will show below my neural network file.

neuralNetwork.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

class Neural_Network:

    def neural_network(self, n_df):
        df = n_df.copy()
        df = df.replace('^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
        #df['itemId'] = df['itemId'].astype(int)
        df['listingType'] = pd.get_dummies(df['listingType'])
        df['endPrice'] = df['endPrice'].astype(float)
        df['shippingServiceCost'] = df['shippingServiceCost'].astype(float)
        #df['shippingServiceCost'] = df['shippingServiceCost'].interpolate()
        df['shippingServiceCost'] = df['shippingServiceCost'].fillna(df['shippingServiceCost'].mean())
        df['bidCount'] = df['bidCount'].astype(np.float)
        #df['bidCount'] = df['bidCount'].interpolate()
        df['bidCount'] = df['bidCount'].fillna(df['bidCount'].mean())
        df['watchCount'] = df['watchCount'].astype(np.float)
        #df['watchCount'] = df['watchCount'].interpolate()
        df['watchCount'] = df['watchCount'].fillna(df['watchCount'].mean())
        df['returnsAccepted'] = pd.get_dummies(df['returnsAccepted'])
        df['handlingTime'] = df['handlingTime'].astype(int)
        df['sellerUserName'] = pd.get_dummies(df['sellerUserName'])
        df['feedbackScore'] = df['feedbackScore'].astype(int)
        df['positiveFeedbackPercent'] = df['positiveFeedbackPercent'].astype(float)
        df['topRatedSeller'] = pd.get_dummies(df['topRatedSeller'])
        df['endDate'] = pd.get_dummies(df['endDate'])
        print('\nnull values in dataframe are:\n', df.isnull().any())
        features_df = df.drop(['itemId','title','endPrice','location','endTime','startTime','endTimeOfDay'], axis=1)
        num_of_cols = len(features_df.columns)
        features = features_df.values
        target = df.endPrice.values
        print('\ntarget values:\n', target)
        print('\nfeatures values:\n', features)
        print('\ntarget shape:\n', target.shape)
        print('\nfeatures shape:\n', features.shape)
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=124)
        print('\nTRAIN TEST SPLIT EXECUTED\n')
        X_train = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1)).fit_transform(X_train)
        X_test = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1)).fit_transform(X_test)
        print('\nX_train and X_test scaled\n')
        y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1)
        y_test = y_test.reshape(-1,1)
        y_train = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1)).fit_transform(y_train)
        y_test = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1)).fit_transform(y_test)
        y_train = y_train.reshape(-1)
        y_test = y_test.reshape(-1)
        print('\nshape of X_train:\n', X_train.shape)
        print('\nshape of X_test:\n', X_test.shape)
        print('\nshape of y_train:\n', y_train.shape)
        print('\nshape of y_test:\n', y_test.shape)
        model = keras.Sequential()
        input_layer = keras.layers.Dense(16, input_dim=num_of_cols, activation='sigmoid')
        model.add(input_layer)
        hidden_layer = keras.layers.Dense(num_of_cols, input_dim=16, activation='sigmoid')
        model.add(hidden_layer)
        output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, input_dim=num_of_cols, activation='softmax')
        model.add(output_layer)
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
        history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=32, epochs=100, shuffle=True)
        predictions = model.predict(X_test, verbose=0, steps=1)
        print('\npredictions shape:\n', predictions.shape)
        pred_nn_df = pd.DataFrame({'predictions':pd.Series(np.round(predictions.reshape(-1),2)),'actual_sell_prices':pd.Series(y_test)})
        return pred_nn_df, history
```

I would show example of dataframe columns and values but I can't post images and copy/pasting over to stackoverflow ends up showing a mess. So I will assume you know ebay enough to imagine what values are typical for the features used in the neural network file.
I've tried looking on the internet for people with similar problems and couldn't find anything that worked. I am pretty certain I'm overfitting the model somehow.

Example of 'prediction' array (output I get every time):
[1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 ... 1.0 1.0]
Example of 'actual sell prices' array (scaled down between (-1,1)):
[-0.104930 -0.866221 0.279235 ... 1.000000 -0.201099]

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `y_train` is from `[-1, 1]` but your last layer is a `softmax`, which can only output from `[0, 1]`. I would rescale `y` to be from `[0, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `softmax` with one neuron at the output layer has the effect of only outputting a constant 1.0 value. You need to use an appropriate activation function, probably `tanh` as this outputs in the `[-1, 1]` range.

Comment: Also I realized he is training a classification model when the problem is really a regression. I would actually change the last layer to be a linear layer.